# Nordtronic dimmer module won't connect to hub

Tags: zigbee

I recently bought and installed a Nordtronic Zigbee led dimmer module for the bathroom lights but I have not been able to connect it to a hub yet.

I am looking for a solution that also lets me use Siri voice control, so as a hub I bought the Aqara M2. Unfortunately it does not seem to be able to connect. If I try to add it through the app, I only get a list of Aqara products, and I cannot add anything else. If I just set both the switch and hub in pairing mode, the light blink to show they are connecting, then the hub says 'cannot connect to device' and the lights blink again to show pairing failed.

Is there any setting I can try to get the switch connected to the hub?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here ... please focus your post to a single answerable question

Comment: Welcome to the site!  While hardware recommendations [can be on topic](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174/are-any-shopping-questions-on-topic), it will be necessary to focus your question a good deal more for it to be a good fit for this site, as jsotola pointed out.  You will also need to include a good deal more detail on your exact specifications, and things like "not too pricey" is highly subjective. Please [edit] to limit to a single, clear question which gives the necessary details to work with.  Thanks!